# If one or the other is true boolean evalution

Tags: ruby

I created check_dog method in my class Dog which checks the dog to see if they have been vaccinated or wormed.

However, I am finding it hard to think of a boolean expression for this statement `If the dog is only vaccinated or only wormed, the dog can only be accepted by itself.`

You can see below I have indented the line I need help with as this line is resulting in 'nil'.

```
class Dog
    attr_accessor :name, :age, :breed, :vaccinated, :wormed

  def initialize(name, age, breed, vaccinated, wormed)
  @name = name
  @age = age
  @breed = breed
  @vaccinated = vaccinated
  @wormed = wormed
    end

  def check_dog
    if @vaccinated && @wormed == true
    puts "#{@name} can be accepted" 
   ----> elsif @vaccinated || @wormed == true
    puts "#{@name} can only be accepted by itself"
    else
    puts "#{@name} cannot be accepted"
    end
  end

end

spot = Dog.new("Spot", 5, "Labrador", true, false)
spot.check_dog # Should return: "Spot can only be accepted by itself".
```

Comment: For some reason it is returning NIL on codewars, however on irb it is returning the correct string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it written does not look right... using your style it should probably look like this:

```
def check_dog
  if @vaccinated == true && @wormed == true
    puts "#{@name} can be accepted" 
  elsif @vaccinated == true || @wormed == true
    puts "#{@name} can only be accepted by itself"
  else
    puts "#{@name} cannot be accepted"
  end
end
```

To keep it simpler you can do this

```
def check_dog
  if @vaccinated && @wormed # both are truthy
    puts "#{@name} can be accepted" 
  elsif @vaccinated || @wormed # one or the other are truthy
    puts "#{@name} can only be accepted by itself"
  else # falsey
    puts "#{@name} cannot be accepted"
  end
end
```

Also note the method is in fact returning `nil`.. you're not returning anything, you're outputting to `stdout`... try changing the code to this:

```
def check_dog
  if @vaccinated && @wormed # both are truthy
    "#{@name} can be accepted" 
  elsif @vaccinated || @wormed # one or the other are truthy
    "#{@name} can only be accepted by itself"
  else # falsey
    "#{@name} cannot be accepted"
  end
end
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. However, it is still returning 'nil' and I am not passing the tests. I think the tests might be buggy.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
def check_dog
  case [@vaccinated, @wormed]
  when [true, true] then "#{@name} can be accepted" 
  when [false, false] then "#{@name} cannot be accepted"
  else "#{@name} can only be accepted by itself"
  end.tap(&method(:puts))
end
```

This way it both prints and returns the `result`.